# Seeing what's new in json list in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm calling a list of objects via json in Python, and I want to do something with each of them.

How can I make sure, when I run this script for the 2nd time, I don't use the objects I've already used the first time?

Example:

The first time I run the script, I get this:

```
{u'status': u'active', u'due_date': None, u'group': u'later', u'task_id': 73293}}
```

So I do whatever I want to do, for example write it to a txt-file.

Then I run it again, and I get this: (first one is still there, but another one is added.)

```
{u'status': u'active', u'due_date': None, u'group': u'later', u'task_id': 73293}}
{u'status': u'active', u'due_date': None, u'group': u'later', u'task_id': 73299}}
```

Now I only want to write the 2nd one to a txt-file. Oh and I want to keep it as lightweight as possible.

Comment: Define "new".  Would be great if you do this with sample code.

Comment: Are you trying to check for an exact duplicate?

Comment: @Alex, or pseudocode, at least.

Comment: I guess what you need is to store a list of already processed objects (or just something that identifies them) somewhere (file, database, ...) and check if you used them already at runtime.

Comment: If you wanted to save space, you could create a running hash of the elements in the list, and then statically store that. Next time through the list, compare your hashes and see if they match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
old_list = json.loads(old_json)
new_list = json.loads(new_json)

new_items_list = list(set(new_list) - set(old_list))
```

Comment: I think I understand, but...how do I save old_json?

Comment: You can modify this solution to update `old_list` after each new set is processed -- this will solve the original problem completely.

Comment: @JCB_K If you're within same process, just save it in variable.  If you need persistence -- for example, each task is processed separately and they don't share state, then just write `old_json` to a file.  Remember about concurrency issues if more than one process could write into that file.